# creating nested dictionary with multiple values from a mysql row fetchall using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, mysql-python

consider i'm getting out from a row where row[0],row[1],row[2] consists of below output and it comes in same order as below:

```
'Testcase2', 37L, 'hydra.c
'Testcase2', 100L,'vendor.c
'Testcase7', 34L, 'template.c
'Testcase3', 88L, 'hydra.c
'Testcase3', 80L, 'vendor.c
'Testcase6', 81L, 'template.c
'Testcase1', 1L, 'hydra.c
'Testcase4', 89L, 'vendor.c
'Testcase8', 41L, 'template.c
'Testcase5', 83L, 'vendor.c
'Testcase4', 98L, 'template.c
```

i need a unique test case names to be printed along with maximum row[1] value so i thought of creating dictionary with multiple values.

```
{'Testcase1': {'hydra.c': 1},
 'Testcase2':{'hydra.c':37,'vendor.c':100 },
 'Testcase3':{'hydra.c':1,'vendor.c':80}
 'Testcase4':{'vendor.c':89,'template.c':98},
 'Testcase5':{'vendor.c':83}
 'Testcase6':{'template.c':34}....}
```

for creating dictionary with multiple values as above please do help me so that later i will do sorting of nested dict so that later i ll print testcase name with highest row[1] value:

```
from pprint import pprint as pp
d={}
for x,y,z in row:
    d.setdefault(x,{z:[]})
    d[x][z].append(y)

pp(d)
```

i tried above code but its updating only with new file name its not appending as above requirement.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: And what have you tried in order to achieve this?

Comment: i have added my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append is a list operation. Based on your example data, it appears you anticipate distinct z's for a given x:

```
    for x, y, z in row:
        if x not in d:
            d[x] = {}
        d[x][z] = y
```

But that `if` is a common pattern addressed in [collections](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

    d = defaultdict(dict)
    for x, y, z in row:
        d[x][z] = y
```

Comment: how to sort 'd' based on value 'y'

Comment: A dict makes no promises about being sorted. You'll want some sortable data structure, such as a list. Initialize with `lst = []`, and after assigning `d[x][z] = y`, also do `lst.append((y, x, z))` (or the tuple y, z, x if that is what your question was asking). Then `sorted(lst)` gives the desired result. To make it look nice, use `pprint.pprint(sorted(lst))`.

Comment: A revision to this

    if x not in d:
            d[x] = {}
        d[x][z] = y
is needlessly slow this is faster: 

going with try/except KeyError catch is way faster.